# How can search by Ajax?

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I am working in codeigniter php. I want to search from database when it match some or one keywords. 
But i don't know how to do it. When it match some keywords in database, in user panel it show some keyword related content.

Can anyone tell me how to do it ?

Comment: `i don't know how to do it`. Go and search in google.. You will get plenty of solutions

Comment: Use `LIKE%some keywords` in select query

Comment: Read the title of the question @krishna...

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do this. If you are new to coding, I suggest you use a premade jQuery plugin, like one of [these](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/14-jquery-live-search-plugins/).

Comment: Ajax is a client side coding,so you cannot directly access DB from there,so you might use ajax request to a php file .In that php file write select query to  search in db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: http://goo.gl/yvwKi3

First 3 results tell you how to do it with full source code.

Answer (score 0):

1) input field
2) onkeyup event
3) XMLHttpRequest
4) param "searchkey"
4) php script
5) db connection
6) query "SELECT * FROM table WHERE textfield LIKE '%".$searchkey."%'"

and the whole way back again...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jquery "post()" method to post your search input to a php file which in turn runs a mysql query to look for the data in the database.
The php file should "echo" the results back in json format. Use "json_encode()" function for this.
Back in the jquery post() function, parse the json result and display it to the user.